# Does any vertex transitive graph have a bounded eigenvector?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Following up on the negative answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747890/is-the-eigenvectors-of-vertex-transitive-graphs-bounded) question, I would be interested in knowing the answer to the following question, which I cannot seem to find an obvious contradiction to when testing for simple cases, such as the hypercube and the circle:

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a vertex transitive graph $G$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n \leq \lambda_{n-1} \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_2 < \lambda_1 = 1$. Given the eigenspace $\Psi_2$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$, can we always find an eigenvector $\psi \in \Psi_2$ with $\psi \cdot \psi = |V(G)|$ and $\|\psi\|_\infty \leq C$, for some universal constant $C$ which do not depend on the chosen graph?

The motivation for that something like this could be true is that it feels like, and I realize that this sounds very vague, that for one single entry to be large, and for there to be many symmetries in the graph, interpolating between $ \psi $ and $\psi \circ \varphi$ for some $\varphi \in Aut(G)$ and renormalizing should yield a more "smooth" vector, i.e. contradicting that the initial entry was so large.

Comment: Take a graph so that there is $v,w$ for which $Av=Aw$ and set $\psi=v-w$. Now add to $G$ a 100000 vertex graph far from the image of $v$. Then, may be you are able to force the kernel of $A$ being generated by $v-w$ and this contradicts your estimate.

Comment: for instance take a square, then add two edges at two corners and a very long line at a third corner. Do this graph works?

Comment: @user126154, I do not understand why any of the two examples you suggested should be vertex transitive?

Comment: they are connected, so for any $i,j$ there is $n$ so that $A^n$ has positive entry in the place $i,j$... what do you mean by vertex transitive?

Comment: @user126154, the property you describe is irreducibility of the random walk/Markov chain, this is NOT the same as vertex transitivity. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph

Comment: I was a bit hesitant to ask this, would you be able to explain vertex transitive in a more intuitive way? I find the Wikipedia article confusing.